# Bitcoin Core recovery with Just Passphrase and Wallet ID

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

I have a wallet ID and my passphrase but I have lost access to my Wallet and Keys due to a fire. Is there a way for me to recover my Wallet? The Hard drive the Wallet was on was physically destroyed beyond recovery. the software used was Bitcoin Core.

Comment: Hi AAroyo, you just asked the same question. It was closed as a duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/if-ive-lost-my-wallet-but-know-my-bitcoin-receiving-address-can-i-get-my-bitc, because the same answer applied to your question. I assume that you are asking again because the linked topic did not fully address your question. Could you please explain what part of your question was left unanswered? Is "wallet ID" something else than an address?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean a Bitcoin address with "wallet ID". Bitcoin addresses are public information and do not give any special access. The actual keys of a Bitcoin Core wallet are stored in the `wallet.dat`. The password is only used to decrypt the keys from the `wallet.dat`. Knowing an address and the password is not enough. Without a copy of the actual keys, your wallet is not recoverable.

Comment: I may have found a second copy of my keys however the HDD with my Wallet.dat was destroyed. is there a way for me to re-create my Wallet.dat?

Comment: Could you describe a bit further what you found? Please don't post any exact details that could leak your private keys.

Comment: I found a notepad with a 2 key strings 1 being 440 Characters long and the other being 2572 Characters long. It was in another backup folder that was only used for mining coins. I'm not sure if the keys are for this wallet or a different one. Me 7 years ago didn't name the file and the only hits I left were Key 1 and Key 2 with the key string no address or other identifier for the wallet they went to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that format. Exported private keys from Bitcoin Core would usually use Wallet Import Format i.e. a Base58Check encoded string with 51 characters that starts with 5.

Comment: I created this wallet back in 2014 (ish) not sure if the Key chains or format of them has changed over the years. I stopped mining and forgot about them till just recently and would love to be able to recover the coins I have/had.

Comment: It could be the backup format for a different wallet instead of Bitcoin Core. I'm not sure.